# Generate class for schema with abstract complex type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, schema

I'm working with some schema which defines an abstract complex type, eg.

```
<xs:complexType name="MyComplexType" abstract="true">
```

This type is then referenced by another complex type in the schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnotherType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Data" type="MyComplexType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

When I run "xsd.exe /d /l:CS MySchema.xsd" I get this error:

> Error: There was an error processing MySchema.xsd'.
>     - Error generating code for DataSet ''.
>     - Unable to convert input xml file content to a DataSet. DataSet cannot instantiate an abstract ComplexType for the node Data.
>     - DataSet cannot instantiate an abstract ComplexType for the node Data.

It doesn't seem to be invalid schema.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After evaluating several different schema-to-code tools the only one we found that was able to deal with our schema (very large and extremely complicated) was Liquid XML (http://www.liquid-technologies.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I have never run into this problem, but I quickly learned that xsd.exe has a lot of shortcomings.  We started using [CodeXS](http://www.bware.biz/CodeXS/) a long time ago.  The product is a web service, but the code is available as a command-line tool.

It has its own warts, but the code it generates is much better and it is free. Plus, it is extensible, and adding your own plug-ins for it is actually pretty easy.

Possibly, it won't have the same limitation?

Comment: That works, but I won't be able to upload our company's xsd to a third party web service (no matter how briefly or whatever guarantees or in place).  At least it seems to confirm that it's a xsd.exe issue :(

Comment: You don't have to worry about it.  Actually, you can download their source and compile it to an exe that you run locally -- http://www.bware.biz/default.htm?http://www.bware.biz/DotNet/Tools/CodeXS/WebClient/GenerateInput.aspx

Comment: We use the command-line version and run it as a pre-build step in our solution.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I needed an answer for this question this week. I tried Liquid Studios as suggested by @ng5000 and found that software to be very clunky. Additionally, the cs output was so complicated that it gave me over 800 lines of code for a single entity with 12 simple properties.

I would highly recommend [Xml2CSharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/), a web tool that generates nice, simple POCOs with XML attribute decorators.